# Error crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, browser, module

I run this code and when I go to ws://localhost:1337 I get this error, how can I fix it?
(I tried different ways on the internet but none of them solved my problem)

error in chrome : crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.

```js
import { createServer } from "http";

const PORT = 1337;


const server = createServer((request, response) => {
   response.writeHead(200);
   response.end('hello world,');
}).listen(PORT, () => console.log(`server listening on port ${PORT}`));


server.on('upgrade', (req, socket, head) => {
   console.log({
      req,
      socket,
      head
   });
});

;[
   "uncaughtException",
   "unhandledRejection"
].forEach(event => 
   process.on(event, (err) => {
      console.error(`something bad happened: ${event}, msg:${err.stack || err}`);
   })
);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Web Socket</title>
</head>
<body>
   <!-- 1 -->
   <p>Message</p>
   <output id="messages"></output>
   <script>
      const messages = document.getElementById('messages');


      // 2
      const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:1337');


      // 3
      socket.onopen = (event) => console.log('WebSocket is connected!');
      //4
      socket.onmessage = (msg) => {
         const message = msg.data
         console.log('I got a message!', message);
         messages.innerHTML += `<br /> ${message}`;
      }
      // 5
      socket.onerror = (error) => console.log(`WebSocket error`, error);
      // 6
      socket.onclose = (event) => console.log(`Disconnected from the WebSocket server`);
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

My JS code is in a file called server.mjs.